# Residue Theorem for function quotients.

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

let $G$ be an open disc centered around $z_0$ of radius $r$.
Let $f(z),g(z)$ be holomorphic functions on $G$. such that $f(z)$ has a simple zero at $z_0$.

Find an expression for the residue of $\frac{g(z)}{f(z)}$ at $z_0$.

When I looked this up, I found that the answer is actually $\frac{g(z_0)}{f'(z_0)}$.
I'm currently stuck at this step:

$$\int_{\gamma} \frac{g(z)}{f(z)}\, dz = 2{\pi}i \text{Res}\left(\frac{g(z)}{f(z)}, z_0\right)$$

where ${\gamma}$ is a closed curve in $G$ that wraps around $z_0$
I'm not too sure how to continue. I tried to pull out a $g(z_0)$ by using the cauchy integral formula but I don't think it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a (in my opinion simpler) way to deduce the formula without power series:
$$
\operatorname*{Res}_{z=z_0} g/f = \lim_{z\to z_0} (z-z_0) \cdot \frac{g(z)}{f(z)} = \lim_{z\to z_0} g(z) \frac{z-z_0}{f(z)-f(z_0)} = \frac{g(z_0)}{f'(z_0)}
$$
since $f(z_0) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Since both $f$ and $g$ are analytic on $G$, and $f$ has a simple zero at $z_0$, we can write

$$f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)\,(z-z_0)^n}{n!}$$

and

$$g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{g^{(n)}(0)\,(z-z_0)^n}{n!}$$

Then, the ratio $g(z)/f(z)$ has a simple pole at $z_0$ with

$$\begin{align}
\frac{g(z)}{f(z)}&=\frac{\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{g^{(n)}(0)\,(z-z_0)^n}{n!}}{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)\,(z-z_0)^n}{n!}}\\\\
&=\frac{g(z_0)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{g^{(n)}(0)\,(z-z_0)^n}{n!}}{f'(z_0)(z-z_0)+\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)\,(z-z_0)^n}{n!}}
\end{align}$$

The residue is simply the limit

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{z\to z_0}\left(\frac{(z-z_0)g(z)}{f(z)}\right)&=\lim_{z\to z_0}\left(\frac{g(z_0)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{g^{(n)}(0)\,(z-z_0)^n}{n!}}{f'(z_0)+\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(z_0)\,(z-z_0)^{n-1}}{n!}}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{g(z_0)}{f'(z_0)}
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: How do you expose the constant $a_{-1}$ in the Laurent expansion of the quotient? That is, can you derive this expression without using the limit? @Dr.MV

Comment: @sequence The residue is equal to $a_{-1}$.  What do you mean?

Comment: $a_{-1}$ in the Laurent expansion $\sum\limits_{-\infty}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n$.

Comment: @phantom Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. If the answer was not useful, then I am happy to delete it. -Mark

Comment: @sequence I know what the Laurent expansion is.  The coefficient $a_{-1}$ is equal to the residue.  What do you mean by "expose" it?  We found it; it's exposed. ;-))

Comment: You are using the definition of the residue which involves limits. But I'm faced with the same question, where the only residue definition I can use is that it is the constant with the index $-1$. That is, without using any limits.

Comment: We have the series expansion $$\frac{g(z)}{f(z)}=\frac{g(z_0)+O(z-z_0)}{f'(z_0)(z-z_0)+O(z-z_0)^2}=\frac{g(z_0)}{f'(z_0)}\frac{1}{z-z_0}+O(1)$$Does that clarify things?

Comment: How do you separate the $O(z-z_0)$ in the denominator? Do you use partial fractions?

Comment: We have $$\frac{1}{1+O(x)}=1-O(x)=1+O(x)$$

Comment: How do you derive this? :)

Comment: @sequence Do you understand the big O notation here?

Comment: Certainly. $\frac{1}{1+O(x)} \frac{1-O(x)}{1-O(x)}=\frac{1-O(x)}{1-O(x)^2}=\frac{1-O(x)}{1-O(x^2)}$. So I don't know why your expression holds. @Dr.MV

Comment: And yet, it is correct.  For example,  $$\frac{1}{1+x}=1-x+x^2-x^3\cdots=1+O(x)$$

Comment: But how do you apply it to the above expression? $\frac{g(z_0)}{f'(z_0)(z-z_0)+O(z-z_0)^2}+\frac{O(z-z_0)}{f'(z_0)(z-z_0)+O(z-z_0)^2}$. But what next?

Comment: @sequence Again, note that we have $$\frac{g(z)}{f(z)}=\frac{g(z_0)+O(z-z_0)}{f'(z_0)(z-z_0)(1+O(z-z_0))}=\frac{g(z_0)}{f'(z_0)(z-z_0)}\frac{1+O(z-z_0)}{1+O(z-z_0)}=\frac{g(z_0)}{f'(z_0)(z-z_0)}(1+O(z-z_0))$$

Comment: How can you factor like this? $f'(z_0)(z-z_0)(1+O(z-z_0))\ne f'(z_0)(z-z_0)+O(z-z_0)^2$. I mean we don't know whether or not $f'(z_0)$ is in the factor of $O(z-z_0)$. Moreover, we actually do know that $f'(z_0)$ is not in that factor.

Comment: @sequence From the definition of Big O.  Do you know the definition?

Comment: I don't see this in the definition (on Wikipedia, for example). I don't think you can do a trick like this by operating series instead of the big-oh.

Comment: @sequence Yes, I assure you that the analysis is rigorous.  I don't know how better to explain in this forum.  If you have $f(x)=O(x)$, then there exists a number $C>0$ such that $|f(x)|\le C|x|$.  So, then $xf(x)=O(x^2)$ since $|xf(x)|\le |x|\times C|x|=C|x|^2$.

Comment: Do you mean that this result can be attained by using the corresponding series explicitly? @Dr.MV